# reload tableView from Another ViewController Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode10, swift4.2

when i am trying to call method from another VC `reloadData()` then the app crash `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` due to tablview nil how can resolve it.

```
FavoritesFiltersViewController.shareInstance.reloadData()
```

[image]

Comment: The crash occurs if `tableView` is `nil`

Comment: yes how i can resolve it?

Comment: The tableView instance is null, that's why the app is crashing. Check where are you setting the tableView property and why is nill at that point. Or add more code and we can check it together.

Comment: I don't know. Your shared information is pretty vague.

Comment: @FedeHenze if i reload it within same class then working fine, calling from another class then crash occor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for every one.Finally after a R&D. i found the following solution. and its working fine.

```
let fav:FavoritesFiltersViewController! 
 fav.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 12):

- You can use notificationCenter for the **reload tableView** data from
  another viewController like below :

**1. You can add this line to another viewController.**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newDataNotif"), object: nil)
```

**2. Add this line(viewDidLoad) to viewController where contain tableView.**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newDataNotif"), object: nil)
```

**3. Add this selector method for reload tableView data.**

```
 @objc func refresh() {

    self.tblview.reloadData() // a refresh the tableView.

}
```

This is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the init function that's triggered when you call `FavoritesFiltersViewController.shareInstance`
It seems that you are not giving a value to the tableView property.

Just to check, you can remove the optional from it and see if the compiler complains because it has no initial value.

Comment: this issue occur only if i communicate with any outlet. otherwise working fine.