# Found Nil Error when reload table view from another view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having troubles updating a tableview from another vc.
Initially I declare it in `CalendarTableViewController`like:

```
func reloadData() {
        print("days array in tableview is: \(WorkshopBookingsViewController.daysArray)")
        calendarTableView.reloadData()

//        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

and it get called from `WorkshopBookingsViewController` like:

```
    func newDate() {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentDate = self.dateToDisplay!
        let components = (calendar as NSCalendar).components([.year, .month, .day, .weekday, .hour, .minute] , from: currentDate)

        self.displayedMonth = components.month!
        self.monthCounter = self.displayedMonth - 1
        print("mounthCounter is:\(self.monthCounter)")


        //get days in courrent month ansd append it to daysArray to populate TableView
        let daysRange = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: currentDate)!
        WorkshopBookingsViewController.daysArray.removeAll()
        for day in 1...daysRange.count {
            WorkshopBookingsViewController.daysArray.append(String(day))
        }
        print(WorkshopBookingsViewController.daysArray)
        self.actualMonthLabel.text = self.monthsArray[self.monthCounter]
        let tableView = CalendarTableViewController()
//        let tableView:CalendarTableViewController!
        tableView.reloadData()


    }
```

in the function definition I get the Found Nil Error.

I tried to implement solution from 
[reload tableView from Another ViewController Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872958/reload-tableview-from-another-viewcontroller-swift-4-2)

as you can see from the commented out line

`//        let tableView:CalendarTableViewController!`

but it trhows me another error:

> `Constant 'tableView' used before being initialized`.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by another view controller? A view controller which is need to be added in navigation stack or a view controller which is already in navigation stack?

Comment: You should correct your posted codes. They are not match. Since `tableView` **Controller** does not have `reloadData()` and `calendarTableView` you mentioned doesn't exist at all

Comment: @MahendraGP. The I call the `reloadData()`function from `WorkshopBookingsViewController`which has a container view with the tableview in it.

Comment: Is `CalendarTableViewController` designed in Interface Builder? If yes, the default initializer `CalendarTableViewController()` creates a new instance with unconnected outlets which is not the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: @vadian. I see, so I'm instantiating a new one instead o referencing the existing one? is it because I'm missing an outlet for the container view that contains the tableview?

Comment: To access an outlet of a view controller designed in a storyboard you need always the real reference to the controller.

Comment: in `WorkshopBookingsViewController` I added the outlet for the container view containing `CalendarTableViewController`but I still get the nil error.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a CalendarTableViewController and immediately try to access the subview in this CalendarTableViewController. But methods loadViews() and viewDidLoad() not called yet and all you subview nil. I recommend you read about UIViewController life cycle in Documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller

Comment: I edited the question to be a tad clearer. welcome to the community

Comment: Wrong! `ViewController`'s main views are lazy loaded and they will load if needed as soon as they called. `tableView` is the main view of `UITableViewContoller`

Comment: so I should just refresh´WorkshopBookingsViewController`insted of reloading tableview data? sorry, I'm a bitt lost here

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the reason of my errors. I was using a custom class for the `CalendarTableVIew`contained in the container view. So I got rid of the container view altogether and I just placed a TableView and have an outlet referring to it.
The initial choice of going for custom class was that I wasn't only subclassing `WorkshopBookingsViewController`to `UITableViewDelegate`and `UITableViewDataSource`but also to `UITableView`..hence an error that mislead me completely choosing to embed the `CalendarTableVIew` in a container, but there is no need for it, as I will have also a collection view I will just also subclass `WorkshopBookingsViewController` to `UICollectionViewDelegate`and `UICollectionViewDataSource`.
Thanks to your help guys I could see where I was going wrong. Many thanks as usual, it's great to be part of this community.